# awk to remove line if match in field is found

Tags: regex, awk

I am trying to remove a line in `file2` if a match is found in `file1`.  The match in `file2` will be in a specific field `$5` before the `-`.  The `awk` below doesn't specify a field to search but does run, and is hopefully a start.  Thank you :).

**file1**

```
AGRN
ABL
SCN1A
```

**file2**

```
chr1    955543  955763  chr1:955543-955763  AGRN-6|gc=75
chr1    957571  957852  chr1:957571-957852  AGRN-7|gc=61.2
chr1    970621  970740  chr1:970621-970740  BCR-8|gc=57.1
chr1    976035  976270  chr1:976035-976270  BCR-9|gc=74.5
```

**desired output** (AGRN removed as it is in `file1`)

```
chr1    970621  970740  chr1:970621-970740  BCR-8|gc=57.1
chr1    976035  976270  chr1:976035-976270  BCR-9|gc=74.5
```

**awk**

```
awk '!/file1/' file2
```

Comment: Chris, come on!  You asked the same question multiple times before.  Provided awk script has nothing to do with this.

Comment: The `awk` command looks more like a wish than a try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep` for that:

```
grep -vFf file1 file2
```

`-f` reads search patterns from file1, `-v` negates the match meaning remove lines from file2 if one of the patterns in file1 matches. `-F` uses fixed strings for the search instead of regex patterns. Unless you explicitly placed regular expressions in file1 `-F` is most likely what you want.

Comment: Thank you, I am not familiar with `grep` but seems like what I need. I have not removed a line based on a match so the `awk` was matching but not as I needed. Looks like I need to learn more. Thanks again :). My skills in science are much ahead of my programming, but I am getting better with help :).

Comment: You are welcome. That's a good read: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565922259.do Plus this for grep: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596153618.do

Comment: Thank you for the books, I will order them and have a look :)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this `awk` to confirm the `grep`

```
awk '
FILENAME == ARGV[1] {to_remove[$1]=1; next}
! ($5 in to_remove) {print}' file1 file2
```

Thanks again :)